# Probability of three diamonds and two hearts when five cards are drawn from a deck without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> a. What is the probability you got three diamonds and two hearts?
>
> b. What is the probability you got three of one suit and two of another suit?

For part (a), I did:

$$\frac{13}{52}\cdot\frac{12}{51}\cdot\frac{11}{50}\cdot\frac{13}{49}\cdot\frac{12}{45}=\frac{267,696}{292,383,000}$$

which is just the probability of drawing $3$ diamonds consecutively (without replacement), and then drawing $2$ hearts after that.

What is confusing me about part (b) is that isn't it asking the same thing?  Diamonds and hearts are two different suits so in theory we could just do the same for part (b) like part (a), but I feel that can't be correct?

Comment: You forgot to count the number of ways you could draw the cards for part a.

Comment: For part $a$ that makes sense, for $b$ are you saying the same process should be done except multiple by what you stated.

Comment: For (b), you need to take into account the number of ways in which you can have those two suits picked; diamonds and hearts is just one example, which is distinct from spades and hearts (which is also distinct from hearts and *then* spades). That's what David Peterson is getting at.

Comment: Would that be $(1/4!)^5$ ways in which you can have those two suits picked?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be $4!$ because the suits have to be distinct. Additionally, I'm not sure where the fifth power came from, or why you're dividing it.

Comment: I am confused when you say, "ways in which you can have those two suits picked" what type of calculation are u looking for

Comment: In part a, you have a particular pair of suits: diamonds, then hearts. In part b, you have to count the number of suit pairs you can get, and figure out how those are assigned to the three cards drawn and the two cards after. For example, you can have diamonds then hearts, diamonds then spades, diamonds then clubs. You can count all of these possible combinations, and then multiply this number by your answer in a, as it is the generalized version of the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the probability of selecting three diamonds and two hearts when five cards are drawn from a deck without replacement?

Your calculation for the first question yields the probability of drawing three diamonds followed by two hearts (except that the last denominator should have been $48$ rather than $45$).  However, there are $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ orders in which hearts and diamonds could occur, where $\binom{5}{3}$ counts the number of ways three of the five positions in the sequence of draws could be filled with hearts.  With those corrections, the probability of selecting three diamonds and two hearts when five cards are drawn from a deck without replacement is
$$\Pr(\text{three diamonds and two hearts}) = \binom{5}{3} \frac{13}{52} \cdot \frac{12}{51} \cdot \frac{11}{50} \cdot \frac{13}{49} \cdot \frac{12}{48}$$

However, considering the order in which the cards are picked introduces extra work.  We can select five cards from the deck in $\binom{52}{5}$ ways.  Since there are $\binom{13}{3}$ ways to select three diamonds and $\binom{13}{2}$ ways to select two hearts,
$$\Pr(\text{three diamonds and two hearts}) = \frac{\dbinom{13}{3}\dbinom{13}{2}}{\dbinom{52}{5}}$$

> What is the probability of selecting three cards of one suit and two cards of another suit?

This is not the same question since we need to select the suits.  Choose the suit from which three cards are drawn.  Choose three cards from that suit.  Choose the suit from which two cards are drawn from the remaining three suits.  Choose two cards of that suit.

> $$\Pr(\text{three cards of one suit and two of another suit}) = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{13}{3}\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{13}{2}}{\dbinom{52}{5}}$$